# app sandbox container-migration.plist doesn't move files

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, sandbox

I have set up my container-migration.plist and rechecked it many times. My signing certificates are all ok and the old app plist is migrated automatically to the container of the new sandboxed app as it should. I have support files in the old app's ~Application Support/Birthdaybook folder and they are not being migrated on first launch of sandboxed app to the new container.

I remove the new container com.robdutoit.birthdayBook each time before testing to trigger the migration. The new container gets created with the app plist in Preferences but the Birthdybook folder is not moved to the Application Support folder in the new container. As suggested in previous post, I tried copying the sandboxed app to the desktop but migration does not work from there either. I have spent days on this and app is ready for submission except for this roadblock.  Any help appreciated.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
    <plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Move</key>
        <array>
            <string>${ApplicationSupport}/Birthdaybook</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    </plist>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check Console.app logs. Filter it by your app name. The issue, if any, should be in there. Other than that double check the paths your are using.

Comment: You can also try moving the app to your desktop. That's actually what fixed it for me, after I saw the console.app logs.